# C# program (Winform and WPF) be treated as virus when create shortcut in startup folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, winforms, windows-defender

Windows defender usually quarantine my program as a virus, and now I found one of these situations: create shortcut in startup folder.

I want the program can autoLaunch when the computer start up, so I create a shortcut in

```
 %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

and then Windows defender quickly quarantine the program because of `Behavior Win32/Persistence.A!ml`.

I don't know how to prevent this situation happen, I've tried to edit AssemblyInfo.cs, it seems make no effect, and WPF don't have GUID code in this script.

I can only add the program folder to the white list now, but It is obvious that can not reassuring for users and the operation is very troublesome.

---

*Update on 2021/5/21*

The trouble is the uncertainty of Windows defender's report:

Sometimes Windows defender deal with it and sometimes not. It may be checked and killed when operated, and nothing happens after that if I compile again. This makes it difficult to reproduce.

I import user32.dll to reference some system-level methods in the before application, but after create a new Demo to test, it works normally.
I've also tried to sign for application and it was quarantined again two days later, but now the report became `Trojan:Script/Wacatac.B!ml`?

Anyway, I'm very confused now. Maybe I need to delete the code for troubleshooting, but it's hard to debug because the time of it's flagged as virus is uncertainly.

Comment: From a general purpose, the autoLaunch configuration is a task devoted to the installer (not the application by itself). A signed application (with a trusted certificate) would maybe be whitelisted by the anti-virus and not be blocked too.

Comment: I doubt shortcut in startup folder can alone rise alarm. What "this script" is doing exactly? Can you prepare [mcve] for us? Without it there is not much to talk about: your software is doing somemething desctructive and defender prevents that.

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/q/1416678/547545) topic on super-user.

Comment: From @invictusWarrior: *Tried to work with RegistryKey ? Is the shortcut programatically made or do you put it with your mouse in the startup folder?*

Comment: Even MS Office gets flagged and removed by MS Defender for 'behavior' problems. The incident was resolved by MS with special logic. Using Defender seems untenable. Reference: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/microsoft-defender-tags-office-updates-as-ransomware-activity

Answer (score 1):

In "solution explorer" right-click on your project and select "Add> New Item> General> Manifest" and then you will see the following code in the first few lines in "app.manifest":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
             If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
             requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
            Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
            compatibility.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
```

in this line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Change `level="asInvoker"` to `level="requireAdministrator"`